# How do you access a member from a grandparent in a member function with a matching child member name?

Tags: c++, c++98

I have a diamond problem setup with classes. For simplicity:

```cpp
class   GrandParent
{
    public:
        ...
    protected:
        std::string name;
        int         age;
};

class   Parent1: virtual public GrandParent
{
    public:
        ...
};

class   Parent2: virtual public GrandParent
{
    public:
        ...
};

class   Child: public Parent1, public Parent2
{
    public:
        Child(void);
        Child(const Child & other);
        ~Child(void);
        Child & operator=(const Child & other);

    private:
        std::string name;
};
```

They each have Canonical Orthodox form, and some additional member functions.

My problem came up with the copy assignment operator of the `Child` class: (need help with what is in between double exlcamation marks !!)

```cpp
Child & Child::operator=(const Child & other)
{
    std::cout << "Child Copy assignment operator called" << std::endl;
    if (this != &other)
    {
        name = !!other.name!!;
        GrandParent::name = !!other.name!!;
        GrandParent::age = other.age;
    }
    return (*this);
}
```

How would these be differentiated properly?

Comment: Don't confuse genetic inheritance with class inheritance. All the classes you have there are humans. So make a class for a human and then model the relations seperately (e.g. in a simple case as member variables that refer to other humans). Diamond inheritance is just too painful, and IMO people think OO is only about inheritance while it hardly ever is the best solution

Comment: The better question is why the derived class has that data member in the first place. Seems like poor naming at best, and poor design otherwise.

Comment: the naming is not connected to anything, I just thought it would be good to make the point and refer to "parent" classes. Grandparent and Parent1 and Parent2 all have different public functions, contained in their "..."

Comment: `Child(void);` no need for the `void` there, that's not idiomatic C++.  `~Child(void);` likewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the question, it boils down to: how to refer to an eclipsed member variable via an object pointer or reference.

The answer is to specify the originating class when referring to the variable:

````
Child & Child::operator=(const Child & other)
{
    std::cout << "Child Copy assignment operator called" << std::endl;
    if (this != &other)
    {
        name = other.Child::name;  // or just other.name which refers to the Child "name"
        GrandParent::name = other.GrandParent::name;
        GrandParent::age = other.age;
    }
    return (*this);
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, the shown code does not require a user-defined assignment operator. The default one will do the right thing, so: forget the whole thing. But, presumably, there must be a reason for one, hence the task at hand.

One simple way is to spoon-feed every step to your C++ compiler:

```
const GrandParent &other_grandparent=other;

GrandParent::name = other_grandparent.name;
```

And, of course, if only the `Child` requires a user-defined assignment operator, for some reason, but the grandparent's default assignment operator does the job, then simply do that:

```
GrandParent::operator=(other);
```